# How to force coloured display of visited links in Safari 5+?

Tags: safari, accessibility, links

Relatively recently most browsers, including Safari disabled the colouring of visited hyperlinks for privacy concerns.

I do not give a damn about this type of privacy and I consider that this is a huge downgrade of accessibility.

Is there a way to re-enable this via a hidden setting or extension?

Comment: Does this include Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a text file, name it visited.css, and put this text in there:

```
a:visited { color: #6611cc !important; }
```

Then go to Preferences > Advanced, click Style sheet and select the .css file you just created. All links you've visited should be in a nice purple now.
(Note that this colors every link you've ever clicked purple, and will override the actual web design.)

Comment: Thanks! I also tried to improve your solution and replace the colour with an opacity: 0.5 but for some reason it doesn't seem to have an effect. Still using colour works.