# How to save a .css file from TextEdit or Word?

Tags: snow-leopard, file-conversion, textedit

I [once read](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40835/how-to-force-coloured-display-of-visited-links-in-safari-5) you could force the color of visited links in Safari by adding `a:visited { color: #6611cc !important; }` in the .css file under *Preferences < Advanced*. In this way, it will turn every link you've clicked on purple and by so override the actual web design.

I like the idea but I tried to do so, but TextEdit or Word won't allow me to save the file. It wants to add `.rtf`, `.webdesign` or other extensions behind the .css.
How can I force to add this to the .css file?

Comment: I know this doesn’t directly answer your question, but if you’re familiar with the command line, you could use `nano`, `ed` or `vi` to edit and save the file. These binaries are all bundled with OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Although it doesn't directly answer your question, personally, I would use something like [Textwrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (free) instead, which is much better suited for jobs like this.

> A general-purpose text editor for light-duty composition, data-file
>   editing (where the data files consist of plain [unstyled] text), and
>   manipulation of text-oriented data.

You won't run into any of the issues you described (including the fact that rtf is formatted text and what you want is plain text - although you can switch to plain text in TextEdit) and you can name the file whatever you wish. You'll also get [syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting) which helps too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, use TextEdit, don't use Word.

*Before you save your document*, select **Make Plain Text** from the **Format** menu. (If the menu says **Make Rich Text** then you are already in plain text mode.)

If you save the document now, you should be able to give it whatever extension you want. Since the file is plain text, you can be sure that TextEdit won't add any additional formatting instructions that will turn it into an incorrectly-formatted CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file then select the file in the Finder. With the file selected in Finder, Choose *Get Info* (<kbd>Command</kbd> - <kbd>I</kbd>).

In the *Name & Extenstion* section, rename the file to *visited.css*. It will likely as if you want to change the extension from something like *.rft* to *.css*, click OK and your done. Move the file to wherever you want and select it from within Safari.

Comment: If the file was saved with an RTF extension, it probably contains RTF formatting codes, and therefore wouldn't work properly as a CSS file, even if you rename it.

Comment: In TextEdit you should be able to save it as type text (.txt). There shouldn't be any formatting codes in that. Delete any that you find. If you need a free code editor try Text Wrangler from the makers of BBEdit. You can get it from the app store.

Answer (score -1):

Just found this while searching for an answer myself - not sure if it's any help now - 4 yrs later 
But you need to go to 'get info' on the text file
And then remove ".txt" from the name & extention
Done!

Comment: No because the file will have formatting info in it as well as the text